# Output not feeding next step of ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have numerous input .txt files that I need to feed into an Arc tool (Samples>DataManagement>Features>CreateFeaturesFromTextFile) that creates Features from text files (the text file contains UTM coordinates of the vertices).

I can get this to work on a single file, but I have ~180 of them to process, and want to loop this.

I am trying to use the "Iterate Files" loop , but the output file from the Iterate Step only gives me the option of setting it as a "precondition" to feed the input of the CreateFeaturesFromText tool.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your model as it currently is?

Comment: Have you set the extension parameter of the iterator as "txt"?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to include a [Collect Values](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004000000005000000) tool between the Iterate output and the next processing step (CreateFeaturesFromText).

[Example from ArcMap's Help Page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Examples_of_using_Model_Only_tools_in_ModelBuilder/00400000001m000000/GUID-9F197B15-27F6-46EA-BAC5-7A722C5A3C4E/) (in a different model, so just illustrating the principle)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though I had to use the Iterate Tables rather than Iterate Files, and then it worked just fine.